# Private property accessibility confusion

Tags: php, oop

I am now really confused about the following:

```
class A {
    
    public function setPropertyValue($prop, $val) {
        $this->$prop = $val;
    }
    
}

class B extends A {
    
    private $foo;
    
}

$obj = new B();
$obj->setPropertyValue("foo", "whatever"); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property B::$foo
```

Why and what is the point of not being able to access the private property since it is a property of `B` object that was instantiated and that the method is called on?

The error would make sense if it were the other way around: `$foo` being a private property of `A` and therefore not visible through inheritance to `B`.

I just cannot figure out why would this behavior be useful.

Comment: it is part of OOP, a private property can only be accessed by getters and setters.  More info here https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: I get it but why cannot I access property on my new object? I would just like to use the inherited method to do it without writing the code again. SetPropertyValue method is basically a setter.

Comment: I mean I am not trying to modify or read any property from class A.

Comment: ``$foo`` is declared ``private`` and a private variable can only be accessed within the declared class. Declare ``$foo`` protected if you wish to allow the ``Class A`` to have access.

Comment: private is only accessible when executed at class's scope level. See [this example](https://onlinephp.io/c/80fcc) for an alternative to access it outside the class but this strategy is only applicable in complex scenarios. For basic get-set, just use getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per OOP principles:

The visibility of a property, a method or a constant can be defined by prefixing the declaration with the keywords public, protected or private.

- Class members declared public can be accessed everywhere.
- Members declared protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes.
- Members declared as private may only be accessed by the class that defines the member.

Comment: For protected, accessible by parent classes only seems to be available in PHP, [in Java throws me an error](https://onecompiler.com/java/3ye2g2nvj). Guess this feature isn't language agnostic and shouldn't be too actually as it is confusing.

Comment: same in C# good finding

Answer (score 2):

Private is only for the class instance using it. If you want to make it available for child or parent classes, but keep it unavailabe for public, make it protected.

```
class A
{

    public function setPropertyValue($prop, $val)
    {
        $this->$prop = $val;
    }

}

class B extends A
{
    protected $foo;
}

$obj = new B();
$obj->setPropertyValue("foo", "whatever");
```

Comment: cool that snippet works also i would suggest to dig further on OOP upvoting i responded per definition below.

Comment: "If you want to make it available for child classes" - In this case it's the parent class which tries to access a private child member though

Comment: @DarkBee exactly, any definitions I read only talk about visibility for child classes, not the other way around.

Comment: I take it back, actually the definition that @jmvcollaborator posted in his answer explains it, I just misunderstood it at first.

Comment: @Tomage Just pointed this out cause the wording is "wrong" in the answer. If you want a work-around use a trait instead of inheritance

Answer (score 0):

[`private - the property or method can ONLY be accessed within the class`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_access_modifiers.asp)

You can't access or set a private property from anywhere else except the class it is created.

[The only way of working with a private property in a class is by modyfying it in a public method of the same class.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: Or via Reflection.